# How can I allow the user to edit items in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I want to create a `ListBox` control that allows the user to edit items, like the list box for extensions in Launchy. Is this possible in WinForms? I tried using Autoit Window Info on that list box and it shows as QWidget (maybe Qt related).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Try using a [`ListView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx), instead.**

Set its [`LabelEdit` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.labeledit.aspx) to True in order to allow the user to edit the names of the items.

---

To allow the user to edit the text on a newly-inserted item, you can use the following code:

```
private void AddItemToListView()
{
   // Add a new item to the ListView, with an empty label
   // (you can set any default properties that you want to here)
   ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.Add(String.Empty);

   // Place the newly-added item into edit mode immediately
   item.BeginEdit();
}
```

Comment: If there are several columns, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx might be good option as well. :-)

Comment: @akshay: I've edited my answer with some new information. That should do exactly what you want.