# Add item to ListBox (ListView) by user

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox

Can i make ListView or ListBox editable by user?
For example: user can add a new item at list (without any buttons).

Can i do that? Maybe give some simple example.

P.S. It is about WPF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I allow the user to edit items in a ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209405/how-can-i-allow-the-user-to-edit-items-in-a-listbox)

Comment: list.Items.add(new ListBoxItem("name", "value"));

Comment: @GrawCube OP does not want to change the existing values but add new ones.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ah, sorry. Now I know this isn't the answer to the question but a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) could be a better control for the job.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

In winforms this is simple with a `ComboBox`. The Text is added if it is new when the user presses `Enter`:

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.Simple;

private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text)) 
             comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
}
```

There was no `WPF` tag at first, but the same should be possible in `WPF` as well..
(Make it editable, set the dropdown to visible and catch the enter key..can't provide code atm)

**Update:** After a rather quick check it seems `WPF` can't do it out of the box. I'm (somewhat) surprised that a useful control (an editable listbox) that has bee with Windows since the 90s (at least) is no longer there. But maybe I'm wrong..

Answer (score 0):

There is no suitable method to do this trick without buttons. Try DataGridView instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx