# DoubleClick in listbox element to enable to edit fields

Tags: c#, listbox, edit

I have a form in c# in Windows Forms Application with some textfields, comboboxes and checkboxes. These fields are saved by clicking in the "Add" button.
Then there is a button to show the entries in a listbox.
Now I would like to be able to edit the fields from already added entries by double clicking in the respective element in the listbox (or by clicking a "Edit" button if it's easier).
How can I accomplish this?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I allow the user to edit items in a ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209405/how-can-i-allow-the-user-to-edit-items-in-a-listbox)

Comment: Take a look at the `LabelEdit` property.

Comment: Do you want to edit them _inside_ the listbox or set the textboxes/comboboxes/checkboxes back to that values and edit them there?

Comment: René, edit them in the boxes.