# How can I allow user to edit items in checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, checkedlistbox

I have created  *checkedlistbox* dynamically and I want to let the user to edit and add items in it.
I've seen  [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209405/how-can-i-allow-the-user-to-edit-items-in-a-listbox) ,

but it is not the exact thing I want.
If you need additional information, please write in the comments.

Comment: And what do you want exactly? Did you try to write some code that does what you want? And if the answer is yes what is wrong with that code?

Comment: Use a `DataGridView` instead.

Comment: I asked you not to downvote the post and ask me for further info . How can you explain this ? What is the reason of you downvoting this post ??????

Answer (score 1):

The default checklistbox control in Winforms don't give inline edit capability. You can make a custom checklistbox for yourself that inherits the default one, and add the extra functionality you are looking for. Or you can have a textbox somewhere on your form with a submit button, so after user clicked on the submit, you can add the new item to the checklistbox. For editing, you can use the same textbox, but pre-fill it when a user selects it, and change submit buttons text to update to let the user know that they're about to modify and not insert, after update, reset button text until user selects another checkbox.